# Magento 2.3.3 Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Profile could not be converted to string

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error

I'm Getting this Error When creating StoreView on Magento 2.3.3 after upgrade from Magento 2.1

> main.CRITICAL: Recoverable Error: Object of class
>   Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Profile could not be converted to string
>   in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on
>   line 3105 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Recoverable
>   Error: Object of class Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Profile could
>   not be converted to string in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on
>   line 3105 at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

Comment: Getting Error When Creating Stores.

Comment: mee too @Abdulmalik did you find what the issue was ? however it still creates the store view not sure what could it be ?